# Draw multiple circles on a Form

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a program that creates multiple circles when you click the mouse. The problem is that they disappear (removed) every time I click on another place.
I have created a class called Ellipse where my circles are saved. Then I put all in a stack called Ellipses.
I have looked at different solutions, but still the old ellipses are deleted.
I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my Code.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int x,y;
    Queue<MyEllipce> ellipses = new Queue<MyEllipce>();
    MyEllipce ellipse;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseClick);

    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;
        ellipse = new MyEllipce(x, y);
        ellipses.Enqueue(ellipse);
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void btnTaBort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        foreach (MyEllipce item in ellipses)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            MyEllipce ellipse= ellipses.Peek();
            ellipse.Draw(g, x, y);
        }
    }
}


class MyEllipce
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int diameter = 5;

    //Constructor
    public MyEllipce(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

   public void Draw(Graphics g, int x, int y)
    {
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        g.FillEllipse(brush,x,y,diameter,diameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did You tried my answer?

Comment: I would go for a List<T>; most of the time you will read them from start to end. And you won't delete them  as a rule, or will you? (Which you can do with a List just a well) And since we are talking about a) user input and b) screen output performance is not an issue at all anyway. The mistake is to assume that Peek advances to pointer. It doesn't.

Comment: Either `Dispose()` of your "brush" variable in `Draw()`, or use the static [Brushes.Red](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/system.drawing.brushes.red) supplied for you by the .Net Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
ellipse.Draw(g, x, y);
```

To this

```
item.Draw(g, x, y);
```

And delete the "peek" line.

Comment: Did the changes but still the same thing the previous circle is not displayed.

Comment: It does not draw it at all without Invalidate().

Comment: Thank you so much. Cheers Mate

Comment: @ErnestoSegovia Check out Idle_Mind's comment. He's right. You can run out of brushes the way you're doing it, and your ui will go nuts.